# get page radio button value to same page form action

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form with a series of radio button. The form is like

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid='.JRequest::getInt('Itemid',0).&bannertype='.$_POST['bannerselect'])?>" name="ftForm">
```

In the form itself there the radio buttons is as below

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; margin-left: 34px;">
            <tr height="40px">
                <td>
                    <input name="bannerselect" id="bannerselect1" type="radio" value="1" />
               </td>
                <td>
                    <img alt="" src="http://www.abc.com/img/1.png" />
               </td>
                <td>
                        <input name="bannerselect" id="bannerselect2" type="radio" value="2" />
               </td>
                <td>
                    <img alt="" src="http://www.abc.com/img/2.png" />
               </td>
                <td>
                        <input name="bannerselect" id="bannerselect3" type="radio" value="3" />
               </td>
                <td>
                    <img alt="" src="http://www.abc.com/img/3.png" />
               </td>                
           </tr>
</table>
```

I have this javascript that validates the radio button selection.

```
function checkbannerselect(){
        var bannerv = document.getElementsByName("bannerselect");
        var check1 = 0;
        var bvalue = "";
        for(i=0;i<bannerv.length;i++){
            if(bannerv[i].checked){
              check1++;
              bvalue = bannerv[i].value;
            }
         }          
        if(check1){
        document.ftForm.submit();
        }else{
        alert('You have not select a banner, please select a Banner Type');
        return false;
        }
    }
```

How can i get the value of the radio button and attached it to the from action.

I tried using $_POST['bannerselect'] which is obviously not correct.How can i get the value of my radio button and use it in the form action?

Comment: 1) you have not rightly formated html in your html code(you have not closed a double quote(") ). 2) you have same id for each input!

Comment: you cannot have the same id foreach of your inputs

Comment: sorry Awlad, thanks for reminding. Let me change it. I try to simplify everything as much as i could.

Comment: Anyone has any examples who this can be done? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on the server, so AFTER the submit. As such, you can only adjust the action of the form through a js form modification.

To use php: Post the script to the server, and let PhP check which radio was selected and adjust your processing accordingly, for instance using a switch

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to go about doing that? I'm a newbie programmer. Any examples?